# Array operations in a map function : Spark 1.6

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a column which is a wrapped array of type struct with an integer and a Double value.

The schema looks like this:

```
 |-- pricing_data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = false)
```

So, whenever this column value is [[0,0.0]] I need to change it as an empty array.
[[0,0.0]] -> [[]].

How can I do this using a map? or using a Dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-
**`spark>=2.4`**

```scala
   val df = Seq(Seq((0, 0.0)), Seq((1, 2.2))).toDF("pricing_data")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +------------+
      * |pricing_data|
      * +------------+
      * |[[0, 0.0]]  |
      * |[[1, 2.2]]  |
      * +------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- pricing_data: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
      * |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = false)
      */

    df.withColumn("pricing_data", expr(
    "TRANSFORM(pricing_data, x -> if(x._1=0 and x._2=0.0, named_struct('_1', null, '_2', null), x))"
    ))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------+
      * |pricing_data|
      * +------------+
      * |[[,]]       |
      * |[[1, 2.2]]  |
      * +------------+
      */
```

**`spark<2.4`**

```scala
 // spark<2.4
    val dataType = df.schema("pricing_data").dataType
   val replace =  udf((arrayOfStruct: mutable.WrappedArray[Row]) => {
      arrayOfStruct.map(row => {
        val map = row.getValuesMap(row.schema.map(_.name))
        if(map("_1")==0 && map("_2") == 0.0) {
          Row.fromTuple((null, null))
        } else row
      })
    }, dataType)

    df.withColumn("pricing_data", replace($"pricing_data"))
        .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------+
      * |pricing_data|
      * +------------+
      * |[[,]]       |
      * |[[1, 2.2]]  |
      * +------------+
      */
```

Comment: basically you are trying to change the metadata of column from `array<struct<2 cols>>` to `array<struct<1 cols>>`, if you have only one row in the dataframe having value [[0, 0.0]] then yes otherwise no. you need to come up with strategy to join columns `_1` and `_2` to convert it to one

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.28] failure: identifier expected

TRANSFORM(pricing_data, x -> if(x._1=0 and x._2=0.0, named_struct('_1', null, '_2', null), x))
                           ^
throws an error at the "->"

Comment: are you on spark >= 2.4?

Comment: No, I am using spark 1.6. My cluster has an old version of Spark.

Comment: Hi, I am unable to apply the datatype to the row.

cannot be applied to (scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] => scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)

Comment: hmm .. the solution provided in section `spark<2.4` will be executed post spark 2